# Why Key Test app shows KEYCODE_UNKNOWN when I press headset control button when the Generic.kl contains KEY 226 HEADSETHOOK?

Tags: headset-controls

My Phone runs Resurrection Remix 7.1(Redmi 3s). When I press headset control button, the key test app identifies the code as 226 but says `KEYCODE_UNKNOWN`. But the `Generic.kl` file contains the line `KEY 226 HEADSETHOOK`. Also I cannot play/pause the music using headset control button.

Comment: Headset is not necessarily mapped to `Generic.kl` (in fact, usually not - it should be in another `.kl` instead).